# Profiling Torch Distributed with Scalene (torchrun + scalene)

Tags: python, pytorch, profiling, distributed-computing, scalene

I am using torch distributed in my code. I run it using the **torchrun** command from my terminal. I want to profile it using the **scalene** profiler.

Sample torchrun run command:
`bash torchrun --nnodes 1 --nproc_per_node 6 --standalone main.py --train`

Sample scalene profiling command:
`bash scalene --no-browser --reduced-profile --cpu --outfile profile_rnd00_pong_5│    fig_path=./configs/PongTuning/config_rnd00.conf --log_name=PongTuning_rnd0 hr_teslaT4_test00.html --profile-interval 120 main.py --train`

I tried combining these two as follows but it does not work:
`bash scalene --no-browser --reduced-profile --cpu --outfile profile_rnd00_pong_5│    fig_path=./configs/PongTuning/config_rnd00.conf --log_name=PongTuning_rnd0 hr_teslaT4_test00.html --profile-interval 120 torchrun --nnodes 1 --nproc_per_node 6 --standalone main.py --train` 
Is there a way to use scalene while also depending on torchrun to run my distributed pytorch code.

I have also tried the following way:

```bash
python -m scalene --- -m torch.distributed.run --nnodes 1 --nproc_per_node 6 --standalone main.py --train
```

and it raised the following error:

```bash
Scalene: Program did not run for long enough to profile.                      
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 2) local
_rank: 0 (pid: 136598) of binary: /tmp/scalenelcqus7e6/python                 
Error in program being profiled:
```

Note: main.py uses argparse and accepts **--train** as one of its options.

I have also looked at pytorch profiler but it doesn't seem to help me. It does not profile non-pytorch related parts of my code. I need to profile other parts of my code to optimize such as the use cases of python arrays and conversions between object types.

I really appreaciate your help. Thank you.